# How to use environment var GODEBUG

Tags: go

Could someone please explain me how to use the environment variable `GODEBUG` ?

Maybe a link to a good tutorial

Google is not very helpful - or I don't know what to search for

Comment: I want to dissable HTTP/2 server support.
I am using  `GODEBUG=http2server=0`  [description:http godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) .
I use AWS ec2 ubuntu via ssh console. I tried to set it in `~/.bashrc` also. 
I use `go build github.com/mypath && sudo ./myserver` for launching. It doesn't work. I anyway have http2

Comment: newer mind: I just use it `os.Setenv("GODEBUG", "http2server=0")` in _init()_

Answer (score 8):

The GODEBUG environment variable is [documented in the runtime package](http://godoc.org/runtime#hdr-Environment_Variables).

Dave Cheney [describes how to visualize GC](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/07/11/visualising-the-go-garbage-collector) using telemetry from GODEBUG=gctrace=1.